# Selecting a cell next to the current cell in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, vba

I'm doing a small vba in excel which change the value of blank cells to "NO DATA". This is what I've done so far:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
On Error GoTo hell:
Application.Goto reference:="DBtable"
Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Select
Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Value = "NO DATA"

'I DON'T KNOW WHAT TO PUT HERE

hell:
End Sub
```

What I would like to happen is that, whenever I add a new record on my table and it contains a blank cell, it should be changed immediately with the "NO DATA" value and then the selection should be on the next cell of the last cell I modified. What's happening right now is that after it change the blank cell to the value I want, it selects the whole table. Please help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Range.Offset` to move the selection, also you can improve your current code (currently it looks for the entire table for empty cells, not just the new record.

The improved code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    On Error GoTo Hell

    ' whenever I add a new record on my table and it contains a blank cell, 
    ' it should be changed immediately with the "NO DATA" value:
    Intersect(Target.EntireRow, Range("DBTAble")).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Value _ 
         = "NO DATA"

    '  then the selection should be on the next cell of the last cell I modified:
    Target.Offset(0, 1).Activate

    Exit Sub    

Hell:
    Err.Clear
End Sub
```

Comment: Juhasz, thank you very much! You are a life saver.